# Sql Formatting Issue for string

Tags: plsql

I am new to SQL Formatting function. I am facing one issue on SQL formatting.
This SQL string needs to be modified in a way so that it would give output like this

```
select 'TIME=~XX2015010106000001~XX2015010111000006TCODE=MEAL~XX2015010111450006TCODE=MEAL~XX2015010113000002~' as sub 
from dual);
```

Output

```
start=6am meal start=11am Meal end=11.45am end=1pm.
```

The problem with this string is that it could vary like `TIME=~XX2017080213300001DST=T~XX2017080221300002~`

Identifiers for start is `XX2017080213300001` ending with `01`.

Identifiers for end is `XX2017080221300002` ending with `02`.

Identifiers for meals are `XX2015010111000006` ending with `06`.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it, I did it all in SQL using a couple of CTE's to break down the steps.  If you want to, you could move some of these steps to PL/SQL for arguably easier processing.  The first CTE creates a table called `tbl` which is the original string.  The second one creates a table called `elements`.  The regexp_substr calls pull out the tilde-separated elements then the regexp_replace calls pull out the hours/minutes you need.

Then, the main query selects from the elements table, building the string while formatting hours and am/pm as necessary.  Note the regex's handle your alternate formatting as mentioned.

A caveat is this code expects all elements to be present and does not allow for midnight snacks.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select 'TIME=~XX2015010106000001~XX2015010111000006TCODE=MEAL~XX2015010111450006TCODE=MEAL~XX2015010113000002~' from dual
),
elements(starttime, mealstart, mealend, endtime) as (
  select 
    regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1), 'XX\d{8}(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}01.*', '\1.\2'),
    regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1), 'XX\d{8}(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}06.*', '\1.\2'),
    regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1), 'XX\d{8}(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}06.*', '\1.\2'),
    regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(~|$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1), 'XX\d{8}(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{2}02.*', '\1.\2')
  from tbl
)
--select * from elements;
select 'start=' || 
  case 
    when substr(starttime, 1, 2) < 12 then 
      to_char(starttime, 'TM')||'am' 
    when substr(starttime, 1, 2) = 12 then 
      to_char(starttime, 'TM')||'pm'   
    else to_char((starttime - 12), 'TM')||'pm' 
  end ||
  ' meal start=' || 
  case 
    when substr(mealstart, 1, 2) < 12 then 
      to_char(mealstart, 'TM')||'am' 
    when substr(mealstart, 1, 2) = 12 then 
      to_char(mealstart, 'TM')||'pm'       
    else to_char((mealstart - 12), 'TM')||'pm' 
  end ||
  ' Meal end=' ||
  case 
    when substr(mealend, 1, 2) < 12 then 
      to_char(mealend, 'TM')||'am' 
    when substr(mealend, 1, 2) = 12 then 
      to_char(mealend, 'TM')||'pm'       
    else to_char((mealend - 12), 'TM')||'pm' 
  end || 
  ' end=' ||  
  case 
    when substr(endtime, 1, 2) < 12 then 
      to_char(endtime, 'TM')||'am' 
    when substr(endtime, 1, 2) = 12 then 
      to_char(endtime, 'TM')||'pm'       
    else to_char((endtime - 12), 'TM')||'pm' 
  end  ||
  '.' time_string  
from elements;
```

Output:

```
TIME_STRING
-------------------------------------------
start=6am meal start=11am Meal end=11.45am end=1pm.
```

Comment: It is great but it does not handle TIME=~XX2017080213300001DST=T~XX2017080221300002~

Comment: only 2 elements?  Hence the caveat. I thought your different format was the DST after the time.  your code will need to check for number of elements and act accordingly.  Give it a try!

Comment: tried that but unable to come up with something..it would be grt if you can come up with something

Comment: What about testing for the word `MEAL` (you could use the LIKE clause) in your string and if it is not there do the same process but leave out the processing for the middle 2 elements?  There is enough here to get you going.